# Cannot use object of type stdClass as array Laravel Error

Tags: php, laravel, controller, laravel-5.8

So I get this error "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array" when I am trying to retrieve data from DB with array

My controller

```
public function openingPage($id) {

      $this->getCaseData($id);

      return view('caseopener', ['cases' => $cases]);

    }

    private function getCaseData($id) {
        $cases = DB::table('cases')->where('id', $id)->first();
        $data = @$cases[0] ? $cases[0] : array();
        if(isset($data->items)) {
            $data->items = json_decode($data->items, true);
        }

        $this->data = $data;
    }
```

Also I see that the problem comes from this line:

```
 $data = @$cases[0] ? $cases[0] : array();
```

Comment: Retrieving a single row from the Laravel query builder using `first()` will return an object, more specifically a PHP `stdClass` instance (hence the error message). However, you're trying to access the first item of an array by doing `$cases[0]`. If you were to call `get()` instead of `first()` you would get an array, then your code would work as you expect it to. If you want to use `first()` then you don't need the `$data` assignment and just assign the result to a `$case` (singular) variable and the condition should be `if (!is_null($case))` to make sure you get a match from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not assigning anything to the `$cases` variable that you are returning to the view.   So in this line:

```
 $this->getCaseData($id);
```

You call the function below which sets `$this->data`, but it doesn't assign`$case` at any point in the `openingPage()` method.  When you then return the view with a variable called 'cases', it has nothing to send:

```
return view('caseopener', ['cases' => $cases]);
```

Either assign the variable $cases:  `$cases = $this->getCaseData($id);` or return the class variable:

```
return view('caseopener', ['cases' => $this->data]);
```